# Access table linked to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to link a specific access table to a sql table, in that if any changes to the access table the sql table will also show the changes?

Thank you for any Help.

Comment: It will be possible, but it will require getting your fingers dirty and writing something to poll the access data intermittently and update any changes into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking if it is possible to set up a replication procedure from Access to SQL Server. I don't believe that you can. However, you can import from Access pretty easily.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Comment: Thats what I thought,  I will import any new changes from the access table.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a linked table.
In the tables list, click New, Link table, then in the file type, select odbc, and navigate to your SS database/table. You might have to create a DSN, if none exists yet.
To create DSN-less links to your table, it can be done in VBA, and can be found somewhere on SO.
Alternatively, you might want to use an ADP instead of an MDB. In that case, the tables in the Access container ARE the SQL Server tables, and the queries ARE the views on the server.
That allows you to use Access for RAD and easy reporting.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the OP is looking to have two copies of the data, not just query one from the other.

Comment: @jmacinnes: you're probably right. We won't know until he shows up gain, if he does, and makes his question clearer.